# Getting correct string from windows-1250 encoded web page with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding

I am trying to scrape some data from a [webpage](http://www.foosball.sk/sk/zebricky/?action=view&rank_name_id=513) with nodejs but I am having problems with character encoding.
The web page states that it's encoding is:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">`
And when I browse it with chrome it sets encoding to windows-1250 and everything looks fine.

As there is no windows-1250 encoding/decoding for streams in node (and utf8 did not work), I found an iconv-lite package which should be able to easily convert between different encodings. But I still get wrong characters after I save the response into a file (or output into console). I also tried different encodings, native node buffer encodings, setting headers to the same as what I see in chrome (`Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3`) but nothing seems to work correctly.

You can see the whole code in here https://gist.github.com/4110999.

I suppose I am missing something fundamental regarding how the encoding works so any help on how to get the data with correct characters would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Also tried the node-iconv package in case it is a package problem. Changed line 51 to:

```
var decoder = new Iconv_native('WINDOWS-1250', 'UTF-8');  
var decoded = decoder.convert(body).toString();
```

but still getting the same results.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the iconv-lite package, but looking through it's code, it looks like you'll need to use `win1250` instead of `windows1250` (see [here](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/blob/master/encodings/singlebyte.js#L81))

The encodings are looked up as [a hash](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/blob/master/index.js#L20).

Also, the readme uses this code instead of 'windows1251':

```
str = iconv.decode(buf, 'win1251');
```

Comment: Hi, I also went through the code and it seems that the encodings are organized as synonyms so 1250 == win1250 == windows1250. I tried that anyway and it gives the same results. win1251 does not work either, the result is different but non ASCII characters are still gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are converting String, but you  **must** convert a **raw bytes**!
If (you are reading something from web, you must read it as binary)

*Example reading file in win-1250 from disk:*

```
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
var Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv; 

//without options (encoding is not specified), 'fs' reads as raw bytes.
var bytes= fs.readFileSync('myFile.txt'); 
//this is bad: var myBadString = fs.readFileSync('myFile.txt', { encoding: "UTF-8" });

var buf = new Buffer(bytes, 'binary');
var translated = new Iconv('CP1250', 'UTF8').convert(buf).toString();
```